# Integral of a trigonometric-quadratic function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be non-zero real numbers such that 
>   $$\int^1_0 (1+(\cos x)^8)(ax^2+bx+c)\,dx = \int^2_0(1+(\cos x)^8)(ax^2+bx+c)\,dx=0;$$  Which of the following is correct? 
>   1) the function has no root in $(0,2)$ 
>   2) the function has 1 root in $(0,2)$ and other outside of interval 
>   3) the function has one repeated root in $(0,2)$ 
>   4) the function has 2 distinct roots in $(0,2)$

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange! Please include some information about what you've tried to do so far, so that you can be given relevant hints/explanation. Otherwise you may not receive an answer as you'd wish, and your post will be downvoted.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The question does not quite make sense, please make the necessary changes. Do you mean this: $$\displaystyle \int^1_0 (1+(cosx)^8)(ax^2+bx+c)dx = \int^2_0(1+(cosx)^8)(ax^2+bx+c)dx=0?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lemma: Let $f$ be a continuous positive function and $a<b$ two real numbers then: $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0\iff f\equiv0$$
>   It is clear that this lemma holds for $f$ negative. I let you prove it or if you want I’ll sketch the proof for you.
>
> $(1)$: Note that if quadratic polynomial has only one root then it has a constant sign.

First remark:$(1+\cos^8x)> 0$.

If $\int^1_0(1+(\cos x)^8)(ax^2+bx+c)\,dx=0$ then $ax^2+bx+c$ doesn’t have a constant sign. The ITV theorem provides at least one root in $(0,1)$. Since this is a quadratic polynomial the previous note $(1)$ imply that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has exactly two roots. To finish we have to prove that the second root is in $(1,2)$. 
For that we use the fact that$ \int^2_1(1+(\cos x)^8)(ax^2+bx+c)\,dx=0$ and we apply the same argument as before.